# Try to execute two shell scripts one after another by using java code

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Which is the code i was used.

ssh.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh root@192.168.1.6
```

ssh1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
ifconfig
```

Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process p,p1;
        String s=null,s1=null;
        try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/test/Desktop/selenium/ssh.sh");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/test/Desktop/selenium/ssh1.sh");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(s);
        }
        while ((s1 = br1.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(s1);
        }
        p.waitFor();
        p1.waitFor();
        System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        System.out.println ("exit: " + p1.exitValue());
        p.destroy();
        p1.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

But it was executing ssh.sh only

Comment: Please provide more information which commands you have tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: you know these 2 scripts won't connect to another machine and issue ifconfig there, right?

Comment: If non-script is an option for you try JSch: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html to send remote shell commands.

Comment: hi leo this is not only ifconfig for other commands are also not executing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the ifconfig via ssh, you just need to change your first script to `ssh root@192.168.1.6 ifconfig`

Comment: i have tried this thing but not working, showing java error:127